# How do you create an intent in C# using Dialogflow API?

Tags: c#, android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/create
I am new to chatbot ,
I have created a agent in dialogflow and i want to create an intent in c# and then use it in that agent but I am stuck as there isnt any reference on how to create intents ,entities in C# code using Dialogflow library for C#

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [this documentation](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.html).

First, you need to create an authorized client. For that, valid API credentials are required, [see here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) for more information. With that JSON file (as embedded resource in this case, but of course it is possible to load it differently), the code looks like this:

```csharp
// Create authorized client
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromStream(
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Of.GoogleApiCredentials.json"))
  .CreateScoped(IntentsClient.DefaultScopes);

var client = new IntentsClientBuilder
{
  TokenAccessMethod = credentials.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync
}.Build();
```

This client can now be used to [create and modify intents](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.IntentsClient.html#methods). The same process is used to modify entities (with the only difference that you need to create an `EntityTypesClient` instead of an `IntentsClient`). Remember to also extend the credentials' scope to include the entity client's default scopes.